# Free google translation

Tags: c++, .net, google-translate

I found online that I can use this URL to take a free translation from Google Translate

> [https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={0}&tl={1}&dt=t&q={2}](http://#)

Where `{0}` is the origin language, `{1}` is the target language and `{2}` is the text I want to be translated and I'm using this inside my C++ project.
With `System::Net::WebClient DownloadString()` method I download the file that that URL provides me.

I'd like to know if there's some kind of limitation in using this.
Can I use this URL in my code to take a translation from Google? Is there something wrong about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an unsupported API endpoint used by the Google Translate extension for Chrome. It may disappear, stop working, or block your requests at any time and without notice.

The only supported API Google offers for their machine translation services is the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).

Comment: Is there some free alternative to this? Thanks

Comment: From April 10, 2019 there is new version 3 of Google Translate API. It is free up to 500 000 characters per month. See https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing

Answer (score 1):

As @一二三 say it`s not official supported public API same as get_video_id from YouTube.

So You have few ways for solving this problem:

- Use this or other crutches [like this one](http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t?client=x&text=%7BTEXT%7D&sl=%7BLANG_FROM%7D&tl=%7BLANG_TO%7D). And always check if it`s works today or not.
- Using official PAID [gTranslateAPI](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started)
- Use some free API like: [Yandex API](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/) [Bing Translator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx)